# Onsubmit Does not function

Tags: javascript, html

I need the function to execute after the user clicks on the Submit button to check their answers and return text depending on the answers given. When I input text and click on the submit button nothing happens. 
The submit button is supposed to execute the function when clicked. Which then returns some text depending if the answers were right or wrong. 
I suspect there is something in my syntax, but I have checked numerous times to no avail.

Here is my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Riddle Me This</title>
        <link href="HW6Part2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>



    </head>
        <body>
            <div class="text">
                <h1 class="head1">First Riddle:</h1>
                <p class="first">The more you take, the more you leave behind. What am I?</p>
                <h1 class ="head2">Second Riddle:</h1>
                <p class="second">What has a head, a tail, is brown, and has no legs?</p>
                Input your answer: <br><br>
                <form onsubmit="checkAnswer(event)">
                    Input your answer for the first riddle: <br><br>
                    <input id="a1" type="text">
                    <br><br>
                    Input your answer for the second riddle: <br><br>
                    <input id="a2" type="text">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
                <p id="response1"></p>

            <script>
            //Initiate function:
function checkAnswer() {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Get the user's input
    var ans = document.getElementById('a1');
    var ans2 = document.getElementById('a2');
    //Compare input to the right answer
    if (ans != 'footsteps' && ans2 != 'penny'){
    document.getElementById('response1').innerHTML = 'Both answers are wrong! Try harder!';}
    else if (ans == 'footsteps' && ans2 != 'penny'){
    document.getElementById('response1').innerHTML = 'You have solved the first riddle, but failed on the second! Try harder!';}
    else if (ans != 'footsteps' && ans2 == 'penny'){
    document.getElementById('response1').innerHTML = 'You have solved the second riddle, but failed on the first! Try harder!';}
    else{
document.getElementById('response1').innerHTML = 'You have solved both riddles, smartass. Have a cookie!';}
}

// When it loses focus call checkAnswer()
a1.addEventListener('blur', checkAnswer, false);

            </script>

            <br>
            <br>






        </div>  
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: submitting a form loads whatever you specified in `action`, or effectively reloads current page if nothing is specified in `action` ... you need to prevent the default action - in your case `return false` in `checkAnswer` and make the `onsubmit="return checkAnswer()` ... or just make `onsubmit=checkAnswer(); return false;` if you never actually want to submit the form (in which case why have a form at all)

Comment: @Bravo  I have changed to onsubmit="return checkAnswer()" and added "return false;" before the closing bracket on my function, but the problem still persists.

Comment: well, you did something wrong - show your updated code

Comment: @Bravo Can you tell me how to add code to comments? I got confused by instructions on the site.

Comment: DONT add code to comments

Comment: @Bravo I have edited my code, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function checkAnswer(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //Get the user's input
            var ans = document.getElementById("a1").value;
            var ans2 = document.getElementById("a2").value;
            //Compare input to the right answer
            if (ans != "footsteps" && ans2 != "penny") {
              document.getElementById("response1").innerHTML =
                "Both answers are wrong! Try harder!";
            } else if (ans == "footsteps" && ans2 != "penny") {
              document.getElementById("response1").innerHTML =
                "You have solved the first riddle, but failed on the second! Try harder!";
            } else if (ans != "footsteps" && ans2 == "penny") {
              document.getElementById("response1").innerHTML =
                "You have solved the second riddle, but failed on the first! Try harder!";
            } else {
              document.getElementById("response1").innerHTML =
                "You have solved both riddles, smartass. Have a cookie!";
            }
          }
          // When it loses focus call checkAnswer()
         // a1.addEventListener("blur", checkAnswer, false);
```

```html
  <h1>First Riddle:</h1>
        <p>The more you take, the more you leave behind. What am I?</p>
        <h1>Second Riddle:</h1>
        <p>What has a head, a tail, is brown, and has no legs?</p>
        Input your answer: <br /><br />
        <form onsubmit="checkAnswer(event)">
          Input your answer for the first riddle: <br /><br />
          <input id="a1" type="text" />
          <br /><br />
          Input your answer for the second riddle: <br /><br />
          <input id="a2" type="text" />
          <br />
          <br />
          <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>

        <p id="response1"></p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists, when I input the text on the first line and then click on the second "Both answers are wrong" text pops up no matter what and after I enter the second one and click the submit button, my responses dissappear and the text does not appear.

Comment: remove last line a1.addEventListener("blur", checkAnswer, false);

Comment: @Dante - because the first time removes the `<p id="response1"></p>` when you use `outerHTML`

Comment: the code in this answer **almost** works - but suffers the same problem as your code ... `document.getElementById("a1")` is an **element**, you want its **value**

Comment: @Bravo I added document.getElementById("a1").value but it did not change anything.

Comment: @Virender Nehra The code works now! Thank you very much! So the issues were getting the tags and not their values and the last line of the function which needed to be remoed.

Comment: @Dante there is no problem with last line but it submit the form when you remove focus from input 1 and call the function checkAnswer()

Answer (score 2):

I have checked your code and found the syntax error in it on line 44 at "a2." in the below code , I have fixed the syntax error. Below code will work fine.

````
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Riddle Me This</title>
        <link href="HW6Part2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
        <body>
            <h1>First Riddle:</h1>
            <p>The more you take, the more you leave behind. What am I?</p>
            <h1>Second Riddle:</h1>
            <p>What has a head, a tail, is brown, and has no legs?</p>
            Input your answer: <br><br>

                Input your answer for the first riddle: <br><br>
                <input id="a1" type="text">
                <br><br>
                Input your answer for the second riddle: <br><br>
                <input id="a2" type="text">
                <br>
                <br>

                 <button onclick="checkAnswer()">Submit</button> 

            <script>
            //Initiate function:
            function checkAnswer() {
                //Get the user's input
                var ans = document.getElementById('a1');
                var ans2 = document.getElementById('a2');
                //Compare input to the right answer
                if (ans != 'footsteps' && ans2 != 'penny'){
                document.getElementById("response1").outerHTML = 'Both answers are wrong! Try harder!';}
                else if (ans == 'footsteps' && ans2 != 'penny'){
                document.getElementById("response1").outerHTML = 'You have solved the first riddle, but failed on the second! Try harder!';}
                else if (ans != 'footsteps' && ans2 == 'penny'){
                document.getElementById("response1").outerHTML = 'You have solved the second riddle, but failed on the first! Try harder!';}
                else{
                document.getElementById("response1").outerHTML = 'You have solved both riddles, smartass. Have a cookie!';}}
                </script>
                <br>
                <br>
                <p id="response1"></p>

        </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists, when I input the text on the first line and then click on the second "Both answers are wrong" text pops up no matter what and after I enter the second one and click the submit button, my responses dissappear and the text does not appear.